# How do I make a div element selectable?

Tags: html

```
    <div class="jw-text-track-cue jw-reset" style="position: relative; 
    padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 
    0px; display: inline; white-space: pre; writing-mode: horizontal-tb; 
    unicode-bidi: plaintext;">&gt;&gt; What, what are the teams?</div>
```

How do I make this text selectable and make this div element become in front of any other HTML element in the same position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use z-index to show the div on top of other elements.

```
z-index: 1;
```

Reference:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Example:

```
  <div class="jw-text-track-cue jw-reset" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;
    padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 
    0px; display: inline; white-space: pre; writing-mode: horizontal-tb; 
    unicode-bidi: plaintext;">&gt;&gt; What, what are the teams?</div>
```

Please clarify what you mean about making text selectable.

Comment: I mean to enable text selection for this div (if it is disabled)